# Completing linearly independent functions to bases

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional real vector space of dimension $k$ and
$$f_1,\ldots,f_r:\mathbb{R}^n\to V$$
smooth functions such that $\{f_1(x),\ldots,f_r(x)\}$ is linearly independent for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Can we always find $f_{r+1},\ldots,f_k:\mathbb{R}^n\to V$ such that $\{f_1(x),\ldots,f_k(x)\}$ is a **basis** for $V$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Is $V$ also a smooth manifold? Otherwise the notion of a smooth map $\mathbb R^n\to V$ is undefined.

Comment: @MichaelM Yes, it is a finite dimensional real vector space.